# Ruby: return vs puts

Tags: ruby, return

I have the following two methods using `return` and `puts`.

Method 1:

```
def method array
    array.each do |n|
      v = n * n
      return n if v.even?
    end
end

puts method [1, 2, 3, 4] #=> 2
```

Method 2:

```
def method array
    array.each do |n|
      v = n * n
      puts n if v.even?
    end
end

method [1, 2, 3, 4] #=> 2, 4
```

What makes the first method return the first item (`2`) that meets the condition, as opposed to returning the second one (`4`)?

Comment: Not an ideal example since `v` is even if and only if `n` is even. :-)

Comment: `puts` doesn't return anything. It puts stuff to STDOUT

Comment: Method 1 returns `2`. Method 2 prints `2` then `4`, and returns `nil`. You have mixed up what is printed and what is returned.

Comment: return breaks the whole iteration of each and the method `method`, too, that is why it yields 2 over all. In (2) puts is executed if the is even, but it does not break the iteration. I would recommend you to read read about the keywords `return`, `next`, `continue` and `break` to get ruby's concept with them, especially in concern to blocks.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm pretty sure every Ruby expression returns something. `puts` returns nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `return` statement inside the first method so that it will exit from the loop when `v.even?` condition is true. That's why it is returning only `2`.

In second method, your loop will check each element, and will return all elements when `v.even?` condition is `true`.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong here. To quote one of the above comments, RETURN will break the iteration if condition is true, whereas PUTS will not. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. RETURN will break the iteration if condition is and put will not

Comment: @iswg: `return` will return from the method. The fact that it also breaks the iteration is a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a new method here

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].select{|e|e.even?}
```

allready does what you want and can be chained with other methods.